# Loop over an insert Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I am having trouble with insert the same value N time In SQL via PHP script.
I have this vslue?

```
Table Info  column (ID,Name, LastName,)
Valus ('',Alain,Alian);
```

Whata i want to do is insert this value in the same table 10 Times Using a While loop for E.G
Or something like that
any idea?.

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    While ($i<= 5)      
    {
       $sql="INSERT INTO arivage
          (ID_Ship,Date_ariv,Date_achat,prov_id,Sph,cyl,Prod_type,Pord_color)
          VALUES
          ('','$date','$date1','$prov_id','$sph','$cyl','$Prod_type','$Pord_color')";
       $i++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you some errors?

what you need is feasible

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO arivage (ID_Ship,Date_ariv,Date_achat,prov_id,Sph,cyl,Prod_type,Pord_color) VALUES ('','$date','$date1','$prov_id','$sph','$cyl','$Prod_type','$Pord_color')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a connection to the database (by using mysql_connect() + mysql_select_db()), and also execute your query after composing it (by mysql_query($sql)).

I need to know what is the datatype of column **ID_Ship**? Is this **PRIMARY KEY** and **auto_increment**? If yes, then you need to change your query from:

```
INSERT INTO arivage (ID_Ship,Date_ariv,Date_achat,prov_id,Sph,cyl,Prod_type,Pord_color) 
VALUES ('','$date','$date1','$prov_id','$sph','$cyl','$Prod_type','$Pord_color')
```

to:

```
INSERT INTO arivage (Date_ariv,Date_achat,prov_id,Sph,cyl,Prod_type,Pord_color) 
VALUES ('$date','$date1','$prov_id','$sph','$cyl','$Prod_type','$Pord_color');
```

Note: ID_ship is removed, and '' is also removed.

This removal is to prevent inserting the same primary key for 2nd, 3rd, etc records. Remember that primary key must be unique. Not specifying it will let MySQL inserts the generated value (because it is auto_increment).

Answer (score 0):

if you need to bind the params here is another way.

```
public function insert($rows) 
    {
        $setValues = null;
    
        foreach($rows as $column => $value) 
        {
          $setValues .= "{$column}=:{$column},";
        }

        $setValues = rtrim($setValues, ',');

        $query = "INSERT INTO {$this->_table} SET {$setValues}";

        $stmt = $this->_conn->prepare($query);

        foreach($rows as $col => $val) 
        {
            $stmt->bindParam(":{$col}", $val);
        }
      
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: why it need loops in chunks?

Comment: Sometimes you need to add multiple values at once. Plus you also need to bind your params. The loops prepare and build the query with the given values and bind them before executing the query.

Answer (score -1):

Try This.. This might work

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(field1,field2) VALUES( ";
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
       $sql.="('value1', 'value2'), "
    }
    $sql.=" )";
```

Comment: I think it should be just like values(),(),() . . . etc.

Comment: The last iteration will add comma and the query will be ended with ('value1', 'value2'), ). I think this will produce error.

Answer (score -1):

You should Add

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

to your code so that the query is executed between the cycles.

```
$i=1;
While ($i<= 5)      
{
 $sql="INSERT INTO arivage
 (ID_Ship,Date_ariv,Date_achat,prov_id,Sph,cyl,Prod_type,Pord_color)
 VALUES('','$date','$date1','$prov_id','$sph','$cyl','$Prod_type','$Pord_color')";

 mysql_query($sql);

    $i++;
}
```